Does magnetic field affect a motor that is powered off
Assume an electromagnet is placed on wind turbine tower. Would the yaw motor placed inside the nacelle (and powered off since the wind turbine is not yet fully installed) be affected by the magnetic field produced by the electromagnet placed on top of the tower. Assume that the nacelle is hanging close to the tower by the crane and is not yet fully installed on the tower
If the yaw motor placed in nacelle could be affected by electromagnet placed on top of wind tower, what measures can we take to avoid this interference?

If electromagnet is powered by DC, no impact.  AC possible.

what does "affect" mean?  it would be in a magnetic field and would be attracted to the magnet.  Do you mean would it damage the motor?

Motors like that are designed to exhibit as little flux leakage (magnetic field extending a significant distance away from the motor) as possible, since leakage represents field strength that was paid for but not useable by the motor or generator.
